# Custom 404 Page NOT Served for extensionless URL

Tags: iis-7, web-config

I am running into a situation,

My custom 404 page works just fine with URL that has extensions.

http://www.space.ca/ssss.aspx
A custom page URL serves up as intended,

however, if you try the link without the .aspx extension
http://www.space.ca/ssss

it goes to the IIS default page. Any idea on why?

This is my configuration , inside system.webserver

```
 <httpErrors>
            <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/errors/404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/errors/500.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that this was posted quite a while ago, however this may help others...

I had the same issue and it was mainly down to having '~' within the path values, sadly this is not what your problem but if you follow the following then you should be okay...

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
   <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/Errors/Unauthorized.aspx" />
   <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Errors/Forbidden.aspx" />
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Errors/PageNotFound.aspx" />
   <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Errors/ServerError.aspx" />
   <error statusCode="501" redirect="~/Errors/ServerError.aspx" />
</customErrors>

<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
   <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1" />
   <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
   <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
   <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
   <remove statusCode="501" subStatusCode="-1" />
   <error statusCode="401" path="/Errors/Unauthorized.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
   <error statusCode="403" path="/Errors/Forbidden.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
   <error statusCode="404" path="/Errors/PageNotFound.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
   <error statusCode="500" path="/Errors/ServerError.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
   <error statusCode="501" path="/Errors/ServerError.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

Of course you only need to added entries for those status codes you wish to create a custom page for. Also remember that **httpErrors** should be placed in the  section, and the **customErrors** within the  section.

You could add the **customErrors** section in as this handles managed code. **httpErrors** section will handle errors for all content.

Please also note one final thing...When you are testing on the local machine the default for both ASP.NET and HTTP errors is to show detailed information on the local browser. You will need to set **customErrors** mode="On" AND **httpErrors** errorMode="Custom" in order to see the custom errors on the local machine.

More information can be found here: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpErrors

Comment: the answer works great , i guess that is the answer of the question .

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
      <clear />
      <error statusCode="404" path="~/error404.aspx" responseMode="Redirect" />
    </httpErrors>
```